# Django: Passing string parameters to class-based view not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have tried following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232851/django-passing-variables-to-templates-from-class-based-views) to pass string parameters to a class based view but it does not seem to work.

the url:

```
url(r'^chart/(?P<chart_name>\w+)/$',
        ChartView.as_view(chart_name='chart_name'), name="chart_url"),
```

the view:

```
class ChartView(View):
    template_name = "chart.html"
    chart_name = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DatesForm(request.POST)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("test")
        form = DatesForm()
        # fetch plot data (default values used)
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'chart_name': self.chart_name
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

the link that is supposed to be redirecting to the view:

```
<a href="{% url 'chartboard:chart_url' chart_name='lords' %}">Sometext</a>
```

(namespace 'chartboard' given in the project's urlconf).

the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /chart/lords/
Reverse for 'chart_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['chart/(?P<chart_name>\\w+)/$']
```

For what its worth, "test" gets printed twice to the console output (why?)

Using django 1.8.11 and python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.04

Comment: Does the traceback show the line that is causing the error? I don't think it's the link you posted, because the `chart_name='lords'` doesn't match the error message.

Comment: @Alasdair yep you are right! I am using this url without parameters in another place of the template and hence the specific error

Comment: Have you managed to fix the problem? If not, post the line that is failing.

Comment: It's OK now. This is the line that was failing: `<form action="{% url 'chartboard:chart_url' %}" method="post" class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}`. It has now been replaced by this: `<form action="{% url 'chartboard:chart_url' chart_name=chart_name  %}" method="post" class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}`

Answer (score 1):

You should access the `chart_name` using `kwargs`:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^chart/(?P<chart_name>\w+)/$',
    ChartView.as_view(), name="chart_url"),

# and then in the view

class ChartView(View):
    template_name = "chart.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DatesForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'chart_name': kwargs['chart_name'] # here you access the chart_name
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

The post you have considered for implementing this is for making sure that a variable is available in templates and that is taken care of by setting it up in `context` which is passed to the template render.

The problem you are facing here is to access a [`named group`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) defined in the url pattern.

Here is more [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) on how django process a request when you try to access a URL.