# Passing data from django form to ListView

Tags: python-3.x, listview, forms, django-class-based-views, django-1.11

[image: Sample of what I am trying to build]

Above is an image of what I am attempting to build: A form that is at the top while the area to display a result list is below. When I hit 'Go!', the part below does not render the list as I hoped. Also, I am not sure if this is the 'proper' way to go about doing this.

The Class Based View that i use:

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'finance/entry_list.html'
    now = datetime.now()
    year = now.year
    context_object_name = 'entry_list'
    model = Entry
    paginate_by = 10
    month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                  'November', 'December']
    year_list = list(range(Entry.objects.earliest('input_date').input_date.year,
                           Entry.objects.latest('input_date').input_date.year))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232851/django-passing-variables-to-templates-from-class-based-views
        context.update({
            'month_list': self.month_list,
            'year_list': self.year_list,
        })
        return context

    # This method ensures that I can customize the list of entries returned.
    def get_queryset(self):

        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902457/django-listview-customising-queryset
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            print('I have entered here!')
            month = self.request.GET.get('month')
            year = self.request.GET.get('year')
            print('month: ' + str(month))
            print('year: ' + str(year))
            if month or year is None:
                return Entry.objects.filter(input_date__month=datetime.now().month,
                                            input_date__year=datetime.now().year).order_by('-input_date').all()
            else:
                return Entry.objects.filter(input_date__month=month,
                                            input_date__year=year).order_by('-input_date').all()
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
url(r'entry/$', login_required(views.EntryListView.as_view()), name='list_entries'),
```

The EntryListView is also in charged of ensuring that the form is populated with the right 'Dropdown values'.

And here is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'finance/finance_sidebar.html' %} <!-- Add this for inheritance -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="well contact-form" method='GET'>
                    <label>Month:</label>
                    <select class="well form-control" name="month">
                        {% for month in month_list %}
                            <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ month }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <label>Year:</label>
                    <select class="well form-control" name="year">
                        {% for year in year_list %}
                            <option value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                {% if entry_list %}
                <div class="container">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No.</th>
                                <th width="100">Input Date</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Tag</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                                <th>Transfer Type</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for entry in entry_list %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.input_date|date:'d M Y' }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.category }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.tag }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
                                <td>${{ entry.value }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.transfer_type }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.remarks }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form class="flex-container" method="post" action="{% url 'finance:update_entry' pk=entry.id %}" >
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ entry.id }}">
                                            <button name="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">EDIT </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form class="flex-container" method="post" action="{% url 'finance:delete_entry' %}" >
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ entry.id }}">
                                            <button name="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5">
                    {% if is_paginated %}
                        <div class="pagination">
                            <span class="page-links">
                                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                                {% endif %}
                                <span class="page-current">
                                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_page }}.
                                </span>
                                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <p>Please make sure you have specified a month and the year.</p>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am again, not sure if this is the right way to approach it. I have seen something called Mixins, but I have no clue how to use them. I did a little print statements while debugging and i found that the data from the forms indeed are able to be accessed inside the `get_queryset()` method. I also made sure that my DB had such a record and i even typed it in my python shell to be sure that the query is not faulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if-else` statement in your view is wrong. `if month or year is None:` will always evaluate to true since it can be rewritten as `if (month) or (year is None)` and you are actually posting month value to your view.

Instead, you could rewrite it as: `if month is None or year is None:`.