# How to pass a value to the template in class based views in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to send a value of a variable to a `PostDetail` template,
Here's the function of the `views.py` file

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.view_count += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        texts = self.object.content
        Read_Time=get_read_time(texts)
        print(Read_Time)
        return context
```

Here's the output of the terminal:-

```
[04/Sep/2020 19:29:04] "GET /post/this-blog-contains-an-image-with-it/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6089
0:02:00
[04/Sep/2020 19:29:24] "GET /post/this-blog-contains-an-image-with-it/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6089
```

I want to send the `0:02:00` to my template, How can I make this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django passing variables to templates from class based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232851/django-passing-variables-to-templates-from-class-based-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to make a method in the **`Post`** model as

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # your fields
    
    def read_time(self):
        return get_read_time(self.content)
```

Then you can access the read time in the template by

```
{{ object.read_time }}
```