# How to add username in url django

Tags: python, django

New to Django, this is a simple blog post app. How do i include the name of a post's author in the url?

```
 urlpatterns = [
        path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    ]
```

post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post
```

Comment: Does this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232851/django-passing-variables-to-templates-from-class-based-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra parameter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<str:author>/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

in the view, you can filter on the author such that if the author's username is incorrect, it will not present any content:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author__username=self.kwargs['author']
        )
```

We can generate a URL for a `Post` object with the [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) which includes the username of the author:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'id': self.pk, 'author': self.author.username})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I'm getting this error "Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post\\/(?P<author>[^/]+)\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']"

Comment: @sokoine: you likely have a `{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}`, but it thus needs the username of the author, so: `{% url 'post-detail' author=post.author.username pk=post.id %}`.